# How to move a view based on validation uikit swift

Tags: uikit, frame, auto

I have a validation inside of my app and a textfield both are located on different areas of the same screen.

Textfield is on  y = 200

Validation Button is on y = 800

Whenever I am at the point of the validating of y = 800 and my textfield is empty I need to automatically scroll on the background to y which is 200 from y = 800.

In short
if textfield is empty I need to go to this specific place (y=200) which is located in the beginning of the app.

I am not sure how to do it in uikit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UIScrollView, you can call `scrollRectToVisible` and pass the textField's frame as parameter to this function.

```
scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(textField.frame, animated: true)
```

Comment: Its brilliant it works as I need but the problem it goes away from the textfield. like the textField is in the middle but it goes to the top.

Comment: This goes to the top because frame value gives us origin as x: 0 y: 0. This leads an exception for us. Set the first parameter as `textField.bounds`. This might help. Or you can calculate the visible area by your view.

Comment: The problem is if I will set the x and y my content view contain a table view so the height of my content view could change sometimes and because of that the offsets will be changing as well. That's my challenge I need to go specifically to a textfield. Unfortunately textField.bounds. Didn't fixed the problem